# How to remove a Parcel from a Depot in RinSim

Tags: rinsim

How can one remove a Parcel object from a Depot such that we can pick it up with a Vehicle? There is a method called addParcelIn(), but we cannot find its counterpart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The current version (RinSim 4.4.3) doesn't support picking up a `Parcel` inside a `Depot`. A workaround is to add the parcel to the `RoadModel` at the same location as the depot, take a look at `RoadModel.addObjectAtSamePosition(..)`. Pickups can then be done via `PDPModel.pickup(..)`.

Comment: Hi Rinde, thanks, that explains it :) We've build an own class to replace the depot, now it seems to do the trick!